# keyup event not triggering for first word on phonegap 3 android 4.3 app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

Cordova Phonegap 3.0
Testing on Nexus 4 (Android 4.3) - specifically using the new native [Android gesture keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin).

The `<body>` in my www/index.html just contains a textarea, jQuery v1.10.2 and a `<script>` which listens for a keyup event, and triggers an alert. It works if I enter single characters, and also when I swipe words, but just not for the first word.

So if I load the app, focus the textarea and swipe a word it wont trigger, but then if I swipe a 2nd word it will trigger (and for all subsequent words). If I delete everything and start again, the same thing happens. I can only assume it's something to do with the auto-inserted space between words, because if I manually enter a space (for which it does trigger) and then swipe a word it doesn't trigger.

Weirdly though, I think this must be a problem with Phonegap (or embedded web views) because if I visit this [codepen](http://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/EKqrc) on my phone in the default browser (Chrome), it DOES trigger for the first word.

**Update**: I just discovered the "input" event, which is a workaround:

```
$("#text").on("input", function() {...});
```

But I just checked another Phonegap app ([HealthTap](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.healthtap.userhtexpress)) on Google Play, and found that it suffers from the same issue (the "Medical or Grad School" input on the Doctor signup page), so I guess this is a Phonegap bug?